# showing an operator is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have that H is an inner product space with inner product $( . , . )$ over the complex numbers, and $T∈L(H,H)$.  Let $R=T+T^*$, $S=T-T^*$ .

If I suppose T is normal, how do I show that :

1) $T^*$ is normal and

2) $R∘S=T∘T-T^*∘T^*$

I'm having trouble even getting started on this problem.  I appreciate any and all help.  Thanks!

Comment: what are R and S?

Comment: oops, I forgot to add that. I just edited my question to say what R and S are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions:

1. T normal <=> TT* = T*T
2. T* normal <=> T*T** = T**T*

Furthermore we have the following properties of the adjoint:

1. T** = T
2. (R + S)* = R* + S*

can you take it from there?

Comment: I guess I'm just struggling with notation.  For instance, for number 1, how do I express T.  Would I express T as $(T(\alpha),\beta)$ and show that $(T(\alpha),\beta)$=$(\alpha,T(\beta)$?

Comment: ok, let me edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: So for #1, could I say something like:

$T=(T\alpha,\beta),  T^*=(\alpha,T\beta)$
So to show it is normal, show that $(\alpha,T^*\beta)(T\alpha,\beta)$=$(T\alpha,\beta)(\alpha,T^*\beta)$?

Comment: You can derive all those proofs directly from the definitions and properties. for #1 you have to show that the T* is normal. That is you have to show T*T** = T**T*. But you know from the properties of the adjoint operator that T**=T. Therefore T*T=TT* and you know this is true because T is normal. QED

Comment: for #2: $(T+T^*)(T-T^*) = TT -TT^* +T^*T -T^*T^* = TT - T^*T^*$

Comment: Thank you! I thought I needed to express $T$ and $T^*$ as an inner product.

Comment: @Kailee you are welcome :)